# Android Websocket connection failed (Galaxy s4)

Tags: java, android, websocket

I'm facing strange bug. We have an Android application that uses java websockets 1.3.0.

From any devices or emulators websocket works perfectly, but not on mine Samsung Galaxy S4. When I try to send a message through websocket, application crashes with an exception:

```
Fatal Exception: main
Process: ru.app, PID: 22920
org.java_websocket.exceptions.WebSocketNotConnectedException
at ...
```

Can you suggest any clue of where to look? I suppose that there is no problems with code, but with device. But I can provide parts of code if needed.

I have also tried to connect to different network without any success.

Can you please give me just a hint? What it that?

Big thanks!

Comment: Probably it is not an application failure, but I really need to know, because I still have not solved the problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

There was a report that `URI.getHost()` method on some Samsung devices returns `null`.

> [App Crashes on Samsung S3/S4 API 18/21 when opening web socket with hostname](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client/issues/74)

The workaround I added to my WebSocket client library ([nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)) is [this](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client/commit/47498fe0464862c0a5bc8abadcb175df42d6370d).